# Is using erase(it) in a loop always safe for all containers and platforms?

Tags: c++, stl, iteration, erase

i want to remove elements within a container(for now it is `unordered_set`) by certain condition

```cpp
for (auto it = windows.begin(); it != windows.end(); ) {
    if ((*it)->closed() == 0)
        it = numbers.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

i know the `erase(it)` will return `the position immediately following the last of the elements erased.` but

Is it mandatory by the standard there won't cause the rearrangement  for the iteation when invoking `erase`? Is it always safe for all containers and all platforms? Say there may be some magic implementation for certain type of container within certain platform.

Comment: What do you mean by *the rearrangement for the iteation*? Container's elements can be rearranged, iterators can be invalidated, that's why erase() returns the following iterator.

Comment: @S.M. say after the `erase` and the **rearrangement**, next we continue the iteration, i wonder is the sequential iteration meet the iterated element or skip the uniterated element by the **rearrangement**.

Comment: After an iterator is invalidated, particularly after erase(), no iteration is possible. Attempt of using of an invalidated iterator is undefined behaviour. You can't expect the iteration meets or skips the next element. Consult the manuals of each container about when iterators are invalidated.

Comment: *"Is it always safe for all containers"*. I might write one container for which it is unsafe. so no :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard requires that `unordered_set::erase` preserve the order of remaining elements, and return an iterator immediately following those being erased. Therefore, the loop you show is well-defined.

> **[unord.req]/14** ... The `erase` members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements, and preserve the relative order of the elements that are not erased.

> **[unord.req]/11, Table 91** `a.erase(q)` Erases the element pointed to by `q`. Returns the iterator immediately following `q` prior to the erasure.

Comment: Could you tell me where to find these detailed standards? i could not find these phases from cppreference or other sites.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links . For the record, cppreference [documentation for `unordered_set::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/erase) does have this to say: "The order of the elements that are not erased is preserved. (This makes it possible to erase individual elements while iterating through the container.)"